# _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast)

Tags: dart, integer, double

```
Future<void> _fetchChartData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=${widget.symbol}&resolution=${widget.resolution}&from=${widget.fewDaysAgoTimestamp}&to=${widget.currentTimestamp}&token=$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      final List<_ChartData> newChartData = [];

      final List<double> values = List.castFrom(data['c']);
      final List<int> timestamps = List.castFrom(data['t']);

      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        final DateTime date =
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamps[i] * 1000);
        var randomValue = values[i];
        newChartData.add(
          _ChartData(date, randomValue),
        );

        if (i == 0) {
          _maxValue = _minValue = randomValue.toInt();
        } else {
          _maxValue = max(_maxValue, randomValue.toInt());
          _minValue = min(_minValue, randomValue.toInt());
        }
      }

      setState(() {
        _chartData = newChartData;
        _isGoingUp = _chartData.first.y <= _chartData.last.y;
      });
    }
  }
```

'''
var randomValue = values[i];
'''
In this line i am getting error like "_TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast)"

In initstate api call is done but shows this error So can you help me to find error and what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 2):

In Dart, the term "cast" means treating an object as a different type.  It does not apply any kind of transformation to that object.

You have:

```dart
final data = json.decode(response.body);
...
final List<double> values = List.castFrom(data['c']);
```

If `data` contains `int`s and not `double`s, then `List<double>.castFrom` will not help you, and you will end up with a `TypeError` when you try to access an `int` element.   You instead should explicitly convert the elements to `double`s.  For example:

```dart
final List<double> values = [for (var n in data['c'] ?? []) n.toDouble()];
```

or:

```dart
final List<double> values = data['c']?.map((n) => n.toDouble()).toList();
```